# How to rotate an UIImageView around it's own center?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, rotation

I'm re-introducing myself to iOS programming and am running into a seemingly simple problem. I have been following [this example about how to rotate a image according to the user's heading](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449309572/4dot-digital-compass/id761371). The crucial part is:

```
float heading = -1.0f * M_PI * newHeading.magneticHeading / 180.0f;
arrowImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(heading);
```

The image is indeed rotated but the center doesn't seem to be the anchor point for the rotation. I've been googling but can't figure it out. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Here's a screenshot in case it isn't clear: in the initial state, the label is centered in the circle and the white square is centered in the image:

[image]

Comment: You can set the anchorpoint of a layer directly view.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint;

Comment: anchorPoint **is** (0.5, 0.5) by default, aka center of the view. Something else is the problem here, we need more details.

Comment: What kind of detail would you need?

Answer (score 2):

This code works for my:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
UIImageView *imageToMove = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

CATransform3D rotationTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(1.0f * M_PI, 0, 0, 1.0);

CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:rotationTransform];
rotationAnimation.duration = 0.6f;
rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX;

[imageToMove.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
[self.view addSubview:imageToMove];
```

Comment: Don't your x and y need to be centered to the image?  This should still (if documentation is correct) rotate about the top left corner of the image, not the center of the image.

Comment: I though so, but it works fine like that, it rotates about centre of the image.

Comment: Interesting to know :-)

Comment: This definitely got me one step further: the image now rotates around its center. Thanks a lot for that!

The rotation animation will be triggered whenever the heading is updated and I'd want my arrow to point towards a fixed point/location. I don't quite understand how to tweak the parameters in your code to keep the "arrow" stable and pointing towards the fixed location. (Sorry for these low level questions, I am just starting to wrap my head around all this...)

Answer (score 0):

Swift port of Greg's code

```
    let rotationTransform: CATransform3D = CATransform3DMakeRotation(.pi, 0, 0, 1.0);
    let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform");
    rotationAnimation.toValue = NSValue(caTransform3D: rotationTransform)
    rotationAnimation.duration = 0.6;
    rotationAnimation.isCumulative = true;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity;
    progressArc.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey:"rotationAnimation")
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code for your case

```
var angle=0;

self.btnImage.center=CGPointMake(self.btnImage.center.x, self.btnImage.center.y);
            self.btnImage.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (angle);
            angle+=0.15;
```

keep the above one into method, use the time interval or call the method when ever you want to change the angle of the image.

Comment: This answer is so bad it hurts.